# Regular Expression matching either a single special character OR a particular sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

Not sure if I'm doing this right:

```
/(https?:\/\/\S+)(\s|(& nbsp;))?/g;
```

This should match a URL beginning with http(s):// and ending with a space character or a & nbsp;

So the problem is this part:

```
(\s|(& nbsp;))?
```

That should mean: match either a white space or a & nbsp; but it doesn't work. It never matches for a & nbsp; and just continues until it finds a white space.

I'm not looking for any other http regexp, I'm not looking for a javascript library solution, I'm happy with this, I just want to figure out that last portion.

**Edit:** some kind of bug in the code formatting on this site, there isn't a space between & and nbsp; but this site turns it into a space if I get rid of that separating space.

Comment: Tried to get the formatting correct by using &amp;nbsp;. The problem is that &nbsp; is a valid HTML code for non-breaking space, and markdown allows HTML to be inserted.

Comment: @workmad3: &amp;nbsp; does the trick in plain text. Ampersand followed by "nbsp;" in backticks will render the desired sequence, but I couldn't figure out how to do it in a preformatted block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\S+` bit is greedy, and will match as many non-space characters as possible, **including** any `&nbsp;` that might be there. Change it to it's ungreedy equivalent `\S+?`, and you'll probably have better luck:

`/(https?:\/\/\S+?)(\s|&nbsp;|$)/g;`

*(Updated because I overlooked the trailing `?`.)*

Comment: No that just matches only the first non word character now.

Comment: I mean non-whitespace character, so it maches http://w  and not http:/www.cnn.com for example

Comment: @apphacker, OK, that made sense. I overlooked the trailing question mark. I presume you placed it there because you incidentally want to match these URLs at the end of the string? The easiest way out of that is to match either whitspace, or & nbsp; or the end of the string.